# Typescript - is not assignable to type never

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to dynamically set the state for one of my Vue js components and am receiving a typescript error when trying to do so:

```
  methods: {
    resetPage() {
      interface ResetStateItems {
        selected: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[];
        selectedDirectory: string;
        artifacts: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[];
        isLoadingDirectory: boolean;
        restoreComplete: boolean;
        isProcessingBackupRestore: boolean;
      }

      const resetStateItems: ResetStateItems = {
        selected: [],
        selectedDirectory: '/',
        artifacts: [],
        isLoadingDirectory: false,
        restoreComplete: false,
        isProcessingBackupRestore: false,
      };

      Object.keys(resetStateItems).forEach((stateItem: string) => {
        this[stateItem as keyof ResetStateItems] =
          resetStateItems[stateItem as keyof ResetStateItems];
      });
    },
  }
```

Typescript is throwing me an error:

```
ERROR in /app/src/views/my-file.vue(484,9):
my-project    | 484:9 Type 'string | boolean | WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
my-project    |   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
my-project    |     482 |
my-project    |     483 |       Object.keys(resetStateItems).forEach((stateItem: string) => {
my-project    |   > 484 |         this[stateItem as keyof ResetStateItems] =
my-project    |         |         ^
my-project    |     485 |           resetStateItems[stateItem as keyof ResetStateItems];
my-project    |     486 |       });
```

I am not entirely sure why it would be throwing this kind of error as when I reproduce it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po%20rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc%20VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQNUgADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRogLFFTBPB3AExcwABT0xnM9zsyhc9wASmCKhwDQ8ZC8iElzhB7Bo3zcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiS58D0Ii8AoZTJZggFSRxAvADlQAHJhAA5SASAVBFQAeW%20ZF2gldWkgx1QjgUrmkeFATgtOlGWH0KAQiBhwiudokkuiIgMHBx3RYbC43CCctt%20ho-IA3ooSiUFDTUPk0GR2EoAL6U%20DU2lkMhMPmgADaAF1gqnpAArSCwVABeKQPCCFXT1B6gLJSV0nqYFUq694Oc0yicZg9T5AA%20UBx0nMRNyYAICHYewvxvA0lz1IA) it seems to work without any errors.

Is it something to do with the 'this' instance in Vue JS? Other similar questions for this error have not helped as from what I can tell I am implementing it as I should be?

Comment: You should do some exploration into what `this` actually is in that context. My Vue is rusty, but it seems like you are trying to use that to modify component property data and indexer syntax on `this` probably isn't the correct way to do that.